# How does Advaitic realization of Brahman help improve concentration,overcome anxiety,depression,stress, jealousy, helplessness, guilt and sufferings?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, upanishads, brahman, consciousness

How does Advaitic realization of the world as the appearance in consciousness help in manifesting divine qualities and tackling above challenges?  People might desire some or other unfulfilled things and its difficult to put an end to desires. The mind is also extremely difficult to control. After meditation, again one loses the realization that he is Atman and acts as if thinking he is body-mind.

Comment: Does Advaitic realization of Brahman help improve concentration, overcome anxiety, depression, ....,? Yes, all realizations are equivalent. Advait realization is not something different from Davita's. It is possible for one to get one more easily than another. Irrespective of the interpretation - the result is the same overall. Freeing yourself from the bonds of Maya which is the cause of anxiety, depression, stress, jealousy, etc.